# ANDROID error: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.text.SpannableString cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: android, service, broadcast-receiver

Мне нужно сделать приложение которое создает сервис и работает в фоновом режиме посылая через определенное время пуш-уведомления, также нужно иметь возможность менять текст сообщения с помощью EditText. Как раз именно с изменением текста у меня проблемы. Мне подсказали использовать broadcastReceiver. И вот что у меня вышло:
Main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button enter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enter);
        assert enter != null;
        enter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //подтверждение ввода
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 Intent intent = new Intent("Intent");
            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
            intent.putExtra("message",editText.getText().toString());
            intent.setAction("broadcast");
            sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
        });

        Button btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_start);
        Button btnStop  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_stop);


        // запуск службы
        assert btnStart != null;
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class));
            }
        });
//Остановка
        assert btnStop != null;
        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class));
            }
        });

    }
}
```

BroadCast:

```
public class BroadCast extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        CharSequence data = intent.getCharSequenceExtra("message");
        MyService service = null;
        try {
            service = new MyService();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(service!=null)
        {
```

service.receiveNumbers = (Editable) intent.getCharSequenceExtra(String.valueOf(data));
        }
        }
    }

Service:

```
public class MyService extends Service{
    Editable receiveNumbers;
    NotificationManager nm;
    Notification notification;
    public MyService() throws InterruptedException
    {
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return Service.START_STICKY;


    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d("MYLOG","onCreate");

        nm = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext());
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntetnt = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntetnt)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_adb_black_48dp)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplication().getResources(),R.drawable.ic_adb_black_48dp))
                .setTicker("Сообщалка")
                 .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                         .setAutoCancel(true)
                         .setContentTitle("Look")
                         .setContentText(receiveNumbers);
                 notification = builder.build();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                nm.notify(1, notification);
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(timerTask,0,60000);

         }
    private void broadcastReceiver(Editable text) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);

        Log.d("MYLOG","onStart");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("MYLOG","onDestroy");

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.vkramarenko.service">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />


    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver //Здесь есть еще один ресивер который должен перезапускать сервис после перезагрузки
            android:name=".BootCompleteReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
            android:enabled="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name=".BroadCast">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="broadcast"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>



        <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"></service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

быстрый фикс:

вместо

```
intent.putExtra("message",editText.getText());
```

вот это

```
intent.putExtra("message",editText.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Теперь NullPointerException

Comment: сбросьте логи, где именно NPE?

Comment: у меня там был небольшой заскок но я исправил и все же ошибка глубже, теперь просто выводится уведомление без текста.